# Oracle Apex dynamically enable/disable text field depending on LOV selected value

Tags: javascript, dynamic, action, oracle-apex, lov

I am trying to enable/disable text field depending on LOV selected value but it works just on page load, and I want to do it dynamically on client side when the LOV selected value change.

I tried with a dynamic action but it only fire on page load.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Dynamic Action with the following parameters:

- **Event:** Change
- **Selection Type:** Item
- **Item:**
- **Condition:** in list
- **Values:** < The LOV values that should disable the other items separated by comma >

*True Action:*

- **Action:** Disable
- **Selection Type:** Item
- **Item**: < Choose the item(s) to disable >

*False Action:*

- **Action:** Enable
- **Selection Type:** Item
- **Item:** < Choose the item(s) to enable >

Comment: That is what i tried, but doesnt work. Only works on page load.

Comment: Well, I tried again and it works now. It wasnt working because i was using the LOV texts in the condition section, instead of the LOV values.

Comment: I forgot to describe what should go to the Values parameter. Fixed now.